# Web API Call from Client getJson

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a `Web API` which works fine locally. I've deployed the code to Windows Server and I can't seem to access it from my local tests. It would be used by remote clients.

Here is the Controller Code:

```
// GET api/login
public string Get(string email, string password)
{
    return "true";
}
```

This is the call I make from my client code:

```
var uri = 'http://api.mydomain.com/api/login';

$(document).ready(function () {
    //Send an AJAX request
    $.getJSON(uri, { email: "user@domain.co.za", password: "123456" })
        .done(function (data) {
            alert(data);
            //On success, 'data' contains a list of categories.
            $('<li>', { text: data }).appendTo($('#data'));
        })
        .fail(function (d, textStatus, error) {
            alert("getJSON failed, status: " + textStatus + ", error: " + error);
        });
    });
```

Comment: why you need to call api from test - you should mock it in test.

Comment: I am trying to test connecting to the server version from my local copy. This API will be accessed by other developers too. so I need to connect to it externally.

Comment: Quick question "var uri = 'http://api.mydomain.com/api/login';" If you cannot browse to this url then the service is not running have you tried that?

Comment: Maybe some cross domain problem

Comment: @LairdStreak That is a fake uri I just placed there. I can browse the real uri.  I think it has something to do with Authentication. I'm still trying to find out more.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Is the call working on the server? `http://api.mydomain.com/api/login?email=user@test.com&password=123456`

Comment: This works on the server.